# Update linked issue customField when EPIC customField Change

Tags: groovy, jira

I would like to update Issues in Epic based on custom field of the Epic I've tried reworking this over and over. I would like some assistance.
def linkType = "Issue in Epic"

```
    def linkMgr = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager()
    def cfManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
    def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()

    def event = event as IssueEvent
    Issue issue = event.issue as Issue


    def accountField = cfManager.getCustomFieldObjects(issue)?.find{it.name == "Account"}
    def cfValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(accountField)
    def epicLink = cfManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Epic Link")
    def epicName = cfManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Epic Name")


            def change = event?.changeLog?.getRelated("ChildChangeItem")?.find{it.field == accountField}

            if (!change){
                return
            }



    def linkedIssue = ComponentAccessor.issueLinkManager.getOutwardLinks(issue.id).findAll{it.issueLinkType.name == linkType}

    if (!linkedIssue){
        return
    }

    if (change){
        linkedIssue.each{
            def linkedIssueObj = it.destinationObject
            def oldValue = linkedIssueObj.getCustomFieldValue(accountField)
            def newValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(accountField)        

       accountField.updateValue(null, linkedIssueObj, new ModifiedValue(oldValue, newValue), new DefaultIssueChangeHolder())

       }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: The linked issues are not updating. I'm sorry I added this before but I guess I had too much code and had to redo it and left that out.